# How do I turn the if else statements in this program to switch statements? Visual Studio 2019 C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement

I've looked up examples of doing this but when I try to format the code like it, it doesn't work. Here is the program I want to convert.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

double comp_tax(double salary);

int
main(void)
{
    double salary, tax;

    printf("Input your annual salary >$ ");
    scanf_s("%lf", &salary);

    tax = comp_tax(salary);

    if (tax != -1.0)
        printf("your tax is $%.2f", tax);
    else
        printf("your salary is outside the table ranged");

    return 0;
}

double
comp_tax(double salary)
{
    double tax;
    
    if (salary < 0.0)
        tax = -1.0;
    else if (salary < 15000.00)
        tax = 0.15 * salary;
    else if (salary < 30000.00)
        tax = (salary - 15000.00) * 0.18 + 2250.00;
    else if (salary < 50000.00) 
        tax = (salary - 30000.00) * 0.22 + 5400.00;
    else if (salary < 80000.00)
        tax = (salary - 50000.00) * 0.27 + 11000.00;
    else if (salary <= 150000.00)   
        tax = (salary - 80000.00) * 0.33 + 21600.00;
    else
        tax = -1.0;

    return (tax);
}
```

Comment: You don't. `switch` statement is not applicable in this case.

Comment: Unrelated: Do you really want a salary like 150001.00 to result in tax = -1.0?

Comment: @TedLyngmo That could be worth bonus points in tax school ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence of `if/else` cases is the more natural representation.

If the code *must* be coerced into a `switch` statement for whatever reason, the following could be one such possible obfuscation.

```
double comp_tax(double salary)
{
    double tax = 0;
    double ks = salary / 1000;

    switch((ks > 0) * ((ks < 15) + (ks < 30) + (ks < 50) + (ks < 80) + (ks <= 150)))
    {
    case 1:  tax += (ks - 80) * 0.33;  ks = 80;
    case 2:  tax += (ks - 50) * 0.27;  ks = 50;
    case 3:  tax += (ks - 30) * 0.22;  ks = 30;
    case 4:  tax += (ks - 15) * 0.18;  ks = 15;
    case 5:  tax += ks * 0.15;         return tax * 1000;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

*Note*: the above calculates the progressive tax for salaries up to 150K using the given brackets and rates. It will not match OP's numbers above 30K, because the original code has dubious "jumps", for example `comp_tax(29999.99) == 4950` but `comp_tax(30000.00) == 5400`.

Answer (score 1):

`switch` statement can only be used if the condition can equal to an integer case. For instance:

```cpp
int n;
std::cin >> n;
switch(n)
{
    case 0:
        // do something if n == 0
        break;

    case 1:
        // do something if n == 1
        break;

    default:
        // otherwise, do this
}
```

In your case, you are not switching based on logics like `salary == n`, so you cannot use a `switch` statement.

---

Technically you can:

```cpp
switch(static_cast<int>(salary) / 5000):
{
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
        tax = 0.15 * salary;
        break;
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
        tax = (salary - 15000.00) * 0.18 + 2250.00;
        break;
      .
      .
      .
    default:
        tax = -1;
}
```

But that's probably not what you wanted to do with `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

`switch` can only be used to compare integers for equality with the `constexpr` integers in the `case`s.

I suggest creating a `std::map` with the threshold values as *Keys* mapped to functions to make the lookup fast and easy. I also suggest *not* writing the program with hardcoded formulas since you'll have to recalculate those formulas every time a threshold value or percentage changes. Instead, you could add a function that creates this `map` the first time the `comp_tax()` function is called and keeps it for the rest of the programs execution.

Example:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <limits>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

auto make_salary_tax_map() {
    std::map<double, std::function<double(double)>> retval;

    // the thresholds and the percentages - simple to maintain
    static const std::initializer_list<std::pair<double, double>> salary_tax = {
        {     0., .00},
        { 15000., .15},
        { 30000., .18},
        { 50000., .22},
        { 80000., .27},
        {std::nextafter(150000, 300000.), .33},    // to match the <= in your comp_tax()
        {std::numeric_limits<double>::max(), .33}, // salary > 150000, percentage?
    };

    double prev_threshold = 0.;
    double add = 0.;
    double threshold;
    double percent;

    for(auto& st : salary_tax) {
        std::tie(threshold, percent) = st;

        // decrease the threshold a little to be able to use lower_bound,
        // except for the max value for a double.
        double th = threshold == std::numeric_limits<double>::max() 
                                 ? threshold
                                 : std::nextafter(threshold, 0.);

        // store the function for this threshold:
        retval[th] = [=](double s) { return (s - prev_threshold) * percent + add; };

        prev_threshold = threshold;
        add = threshold * percent;
    }

    return retval;
}
```

With that in place your `comp_tax()` function simply becomes:

```
double comp_tax(double salary) {
    // static, so it's only initialized once:
    static const auto salary_tax = make_salary_tax_map(); 

    // efficiently find the function for this salary and call it
    return salary_tax.lower_bound(salary)->second(salary);
}
```